# How to Add Multiple Items to a Product List in OFBiz ie from a CSV?

Tags: csv, product, ofbiz

is there any way to add multiple products to an inventory product list in ofbiz...

ie through a csv file...

this is for inventory management and there are only about 2-3K parts to be inventoried and listed and i would like to not feed them in one by one, it could take forever

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `OFBiz format`. You can find example in any `data` folder in any component.

If you want to use csv(or any others file format), i have to customize by yourself.

**Edit:** You can use [Pentaho](http://pentaho.com) tool to import data, with this tool you can import a lot of extensions(csv, excel,...) and format.

Answer (score 0):

i actually figured it out...  you have to first have a definition file... also to note you must order your input as ofbiz is full of quirks

a file defines the items in the csv, and the web tool will make an xml file out of the definition file and the csv... i wanted this automated so i went ahead and just took the output xml file that ofbiz spit out from the data tool, and made a gawk script that could do it script style